# Is "adj. + infinitive + be" a thing? Or am I understanding the hyphen wrong?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, infinitives

I came across this sentence during my GRE prep. I had a hard time understanding the grammar structure of it. It seems to me that the `will be` in the middle is referring to `Crucial to fostering` in the beginning of the sentence, but how is that correct?

> Crucial to fostering a realistic understanding of the potential boons—and
> perils—of the new drug will be a concerted effort to _______ the specific
> contexts and symptoms that render its use appropriate.

Can you use the structure `adj. + infinitive + be`?

Or am I interpreting the hyphens wrong? Is the `will be` supposed to describe other objects in the sentence?

Or is this just a bad sentence?

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: @DjinTonic Thanks for the reply. I kinda get it now the more i read this sentence. I thought "crucial to fostering" was adj + infinitive is but it's actually "crucial to noun".

Comment: Just remove the two dashes; they are confusing you and have nothing to do with the overall sentence structure.  *My test score will be crucial to my passing the course* = *Crucial to my passing the course  will be my test score* [comment edited and reposted]

Comment: @DjinTonic Oh i fully understand it now. Looks like it's some sort of inverted structure is it? I'm not a native speaker but this surely does make sense now. thx for the example <3

Comment: Yes, it's an inverted structure. It places more emphasis on the phrase "crucial to fostering ..."